# Use Powershell to Get a List of AAD Users (non-guests)

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I've done some reports like this before but this one is giving me fits.  I think the closest I've gotten is the code below.  However, it keeps running in a loop.  I'll export it to a CSV but I figured I can handle that part later.  The *meat & potatoes* of the code, as it were, isn't working correctly. As I said, it just loops.  If I had to guess, the issue is with the `ForEach` section.

```
$HOD_Users = Get-EXOMailbox -Filter {RecipientTypeDetails -ne "SharedMailbox"}
ForEach ($User in $HOD_Users) { 
    Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserType eq 'Member'" -All $true
    }
```

I also tried to get at it this way but I get the same looping action in the readout.

```
Get-EXOMailbox -Filter {RecipientTypeDetails -ne "SharedMailbox"} | ForEach-Object {Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserType eq 'Member'" -All $true}
```

Comment: You most likely are getting a lot of email.  It is not in a loop.  I would export to a CSV file and then look at results in file.

Comment: I dropped it to a CSV but I got 11k lines in a text file.  The company has fewer than 100 employees.  As I spot-check the file, it looks like every user is listed 63 times so I'm guessing there are only 63 people but a Get-AzureADUser command is run for each occurrence. In my mind, it ran that command 63 times.

Comment: As I spot-check the CSV, I'm noticing the ObjectIDs being listed 63 times.  They should be unique.  It's looping.

Comment: It working, you are not getting what you expected.  It may be due to a shared mailbox,  You are reading an archive multiple times, you are reading responses and replies from the same email. Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/troubleshoot/active-directory/duplicate-attributes-prevent-dirsync

Comment: I simplified the code just to export the initial data to a CSV `Get-EXOMailbox -Filter {RecipientTypeDetails -ne "SharedMailbox"} | Export-Csv "C:\Temp\HOD_Users_TEMP.csv" -NoTypeInformation` and I get a 64-line CSV with 63 individual users.  There has to be something wrong with the `ForEach` part of the code.

Comment: I assume all the same ObjectID.  The link says that you may have a synchronization issue.  I'm not familiar with this issue.  I would follow instructions in the link.

Answer (score 1):

- Get-EXOMailbox does not return the userType details for the user account.
- UserType is a specific field within Get-AzureADUser command.
- If the end goal is to just get the list on Member users in Azure AD Tenant (Non-Guest) then you can simply use following command: **Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserType eq 'Member'" -All $true**

Later if you would like to fetch mailbox details for all of these member users use following script sample:

```
Connect-AzureAD
Connect-ExchangeOnline
$HOD_Users = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserType eq 'Member'" -All $true | FL
$output = ForEach ($User in $HOD_Users) 
{ 
  Get-EXOMailbox -Identity $User.UserPrincipalName
}
$output | Export-Csv -Path C:\usernew1.csv -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber
```

Please note script execution would take time depending on number of users in the tenant. Also above script will not return any details or may return errors for member users with no license/mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

The Mailboxes in my Exchange Admin Center looks like below:

[image]

To get **Exchange Online mailboxes that are not shared mailboxes and get the user's principal name** I used the below PowerShell script:

```
$HOD_Users = Get-EXOMailbox -Filter {RecipientTypeDetails -ne "SharedMailbox"}

$AzureADUsers = foreach ($User in $HOD_Users) {
    $UPN = $User.UserPrincipalName
    $AzureADUser = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserType eq 'Member' and UserPrincipalName eq '$UPN'" -All $true
    $AzureADUser | Export-Csv -Path "C:\AzureADUsers1.csv" -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber
}
```

[image]

***The CSV file got exported successfully like below:***

[image]